# Windows System shutdown on always on

Tags: windows, windows-xp, power-management

I need ideas as to why this Windows XP system shutdowns. I've edited all the power options to always on. Is there anything else that could maybe be overwriting that?

No crashing.
Just after x amount of time it shutdowns.
No power spikes or any UPS
No hardware changes
No software changes
No over heating
Nothing is running when it decides to shutdown

Comment: This question is too vague.  When and how does it shut down?  What is it doing when it shuts down?  Is it actually doing a proper shutdown or is it just crashing or cutting off?  Please edit your question to provide details.

Comment: We need more info. This is not a good question which can be answered so if you really need help edit it and provide the info like when you have get started to see this error and any new install program any hardware failure etc?

Comment: Added more will add more as I can

Comment: When it started to do this?

Comment: What kind of PC is it? Make and model? How old is it? I just had one doing the same thing recently, could be a number of things. Bad hard drive, bad power supply, etc... Does the power light on the PC flash amber? If so that's probably an indication of a bad power supply.

Comment: Your edits are slightly helpful, but I'm still unclear on one major point - is it actually shutting down (that is, you see the same screens you'd see if you manually shut it down) or is it just *turning off abruptly*.  The former indicates something triggering a shutdown; the latter indicates a serious problem.

Comment: I've got no idea how it shutdowns. It is left in the office on but next day it's off and every other system stays on.

Comment: Take a look in the event viewer system log.  Look to see if there is anything referring to the shutdown or an error after restart saying the previous shutdown was unexpected.  Two options I see - something is telling your PC to shutdown (scheduled task) or it could be overheating.

Comment: @uSlackr is thinking exactly what I'm thinking, yes.  And if it's never shut off while somebody is using it, all day, I'm inclined to think it's a scheduled task or software triggered event of some sorts.

Comment: Might not be overheating, could be a faulty power supply.  I've also seen a similar symptom as the result of a poorly seated CPU.

Comment: Seems to be consistant to evening times. Can Windows Backup cause a shutdown after it? Nothing shows in the event viewer though and its fine rest of the day.